# assign 50 % of nodes to a certain parameter and the rest to another parameter

Tags: omnet++

Hii I have a code that I need to assign half the nodes to an interarrival time and the rest of nodes to another interarrival
    LoRa.numHosts = 300

```
LoRa.host[0..149].iaTime = exponential(600s) 
LoRa.host[150..299].iaTime = exponential(60s)
```

is there a way to do it generically so that I just need to change numHosts and the code does the rest for example (this gives error!)

```
LoRa.numHosts = ${N=300..3000 step 100} 

LoRa.host[0..(numHosts/2)-1].iaTime = exponential(600s) 
LoRa.host[(numHosts/2)..numHosts].iaTime = exponential(60s)
```

any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should write in `omnetpp.ini` the following lines:

```
LoRa.numHosts = ${N=300..3000 step 100} 
LoRa.host[*].iaTime = index < (${N})/2 ? exponential(600s) : exponential(60s)
```

The `index` in the second line returns index (i.e. position) of this host in the  vector of hosts. The expression `cond ? val1 : val2` has the same meaning as in C++.